# pwd vs directory of file

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have a file and I want to get the directory that file is in. In python, I would do:

```
FILE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

How would I do the same thing in a shell script? If I use `pwd` I would get the current directory of the folder I am executing the command from and not the folder of the file I am executing (which is what I need).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're executing a shell script, `$0` is the name of the script you're executing (see Special Parameters in the [Variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html) chapter of the Bash Guide for Beginners), equivalent to `sys.argv[0]` in Python (unless you've called `shift`).

The [`dirname`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/dirname.html) command does the same thing as `os.path.dirname` in Python.

There's no portable direct equivalent to `os.path.abspath` or `os.path.realpath`, and `$0`. There are platform-specific ways to do this (e.g., [`readlink -f`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/readlink) on systems with a GNU userland), or you manually combine the `pwd` with the path. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9541/find-absolute-path-from-a-script) at Unix for a variety of different ways to do that, but [mrfripp's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/34344/mfripp) [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68216) seems like the most portable:

```
abspath=$(unset CDPATH && cd "$(dirname "$0")" && echo ${PWD}/$(basename "$0"))
```

Or, of course, you can just ask Python to do it:

```
abspath=$(python -c "import os; print(os.path.realpath(\"$0\"))"
absdir=$(dirname "${abspath}")
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is:

```
FILE_PATH=`realpath $0`
FILE_DIR=`dirname $FILE_PATH`
```

Or in bash-like shells:

```
FILE_DIR=$(dirname $(realpath $0))
```

Note that `realpath` is only guaranteed to be available on GNU-based systems (e.g. Linux).

Comment: Presumably his shell script is not `ls`. Also, there's no reason to believe it's the first thing on `$PATH`, or even on it at all (e.g., if you run `./foo.sh`, `which foo.sh` isn't going to work). Also, there's a lot of linux-specific stuff or even Debian-specific stuff here (`which` and `dirname` are in `/usr/bin` on most other *nix systems, and even many linux systems; `realpath` only exists in the GNU userland, not BSD or SysV; etc.).

Comment: @abanert in general I agree with you, it is a GNU-centric answer. However, if you're running `./foo.sh`, `which ./foo.sh` will work (why would you pass only `foo.sh`?)

Comment: OK, but if you're running `bash foo.sh` or `bash ./foo.sh`, `$0` will be `foo.sh` or `./foo.sh`, but `which` won't find anything unless the script is chmod +x. More importantly, what is `which` buying you here anyway? `$0` will always be either an absolute path, or a path relative to the `pwd`; `which` will either return the same thing, or a different program with the same name, or nothing.

Comment: Valid point, as usual. Anyway, dropped the first part from the answer as it was not really relevant (misunderstanding on my part more than anything else).

Comment: Well, `realpath` (or `readlink`, which I think GNU/Linux has had for a lot longer) is definitely a _lot_ simpler than the mess I copied and modified from the unix.sx site, so this is definitely helpful if the OP (or some later searcher) is on linux.

Comment: @isedev Just a note, command substitution is posix, not just `bash-like`.